# Gridview and Expandable listview in same scrollview in Android

Tags: android, gridview, expandablelistview

I want to scroll the gridview and expandable listview in same scroll. How I need to implement and which type of code I need to add for adapters. I using one method to adding these two (gridview, expandable listview in same class) but here I am facing problem with expandable listview child height. I put gridview and expandable listview height static. Expandable listview child items expand remaining top or ending group items are not displaying. Can any one suggest any best solution for this...

Thanks,
Shaik. Khaja Peer...

Comment: You must include some code for reference